# Bug Fix: the tabs in the Physics forum appear cluttered

Tags: bug, design

I am not sure whether it's a bug or not. But if you hover over the menu below banner labelled 'Physics', the background changes to light blue, however, that background comes behind the written texts on the page. This kind of makes the design look a bit untidy.

Shouldn't the rest of the page be lowered or the background's height be reduced?

[image: The banner]

See the `forum appear cluttered`? That! It looks a bit messy.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to describe. Could you screenshot this occurrence?

Comment: Possibly related: [The site toolbar looks broken in chrome how can i fix](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/the-site-toolbar-looks-broken-in-chrome-how-can-i-fix-it/6115#6115)

Comment: Ah, yes, it's the same problem. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can if you want to, but I'd say leave it there. It will be closed as a duplicate and eventually be swallowed by the meta front page. Long-term, it will act as a signpost for the main question, which is notoriously difficult to find (see the list of Linked questions to the right).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty All right. :)